# jquery parallax scroll with image bg

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, parallax

I making a parallax page with backgrounds and fixed div sizes. I fix height and width of the images to screen with jquery. But most of parallax plugins didnt work with me :(

> I am trying to do something like this: http://www.spotify.com/int/
>
> Here is my work: http://jsfiddle.net/Ybv7n/7/

This is my html looks like.

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div id="par1" class="par1 par"><div></div></div>
    <div id="sec1" class="sec1 sec">
        aaaa
    </div>
    <div id="par2" class="par2 par" par><div></div></div>
    <div id="sec2" class="sec2 sec">
        aaa
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to the images' important parts fit in the screen. They could go top a little bit when scrolled. I tried everything :(

Comment: the images are on the screen entirely... what do you mean with "important parts fit in the screen"?

Comment: $(".par").height(window_h_55_percent);
$(".sec").height(window_h_45_percent);

The question is, what to do now ? I just dont want some explaination. What to do and how to do for making it alike spotify ?